# Did any groups or noted theologians in early Christian history teach that the Holy Spirit is matriarchal?

Tags: trinity, pneumatology, early-church

[Count Zinzendorf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaus_Ludwig_Zinzendorf) came to the aid of the [Moravian Brethren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moravian_Church).  He held that the Holy Spirit was matriarchal. Are there any teachings of this perspective in early church history?

Comment: I think this is pretty interesting because in a musical about the Bible I saw a few years ago, which was very reverent and well done called ["In the Garden"](http://www.thegardenrockopera.com/home.html) the Holy Spirit was acted by a woman and the visuals that that inspired made perfect sense. In the Catholic Church we usually refer to the Holy Spirit as He, but in this sense a woman as the Holy Spirit seemed the better fit for the role.

Comment: People might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_of_the_Holy_Spirit

Comment: Was "this perspective" that the Holy Spirit was matriarchal, female, or feminine? (I hesitate to correct the spelling error in the title before this is clarified.) Matriarchal would *seem* to be non-Nicene ("proceeds from the Father", worshiped and glorified together--"rule", to any extent that it exists within the equality and unity of the Godhead, would *seem* to be from the Father) and female seems to have unclear meaning for a purely spiritual, non-reproducing being (but *might* be used informally for feminine).

Comment: Matriarchal is more like motherly.  Essentially Jesus is the eternal Son conceived by the will of God the Father born of the Holy Spirit. Eternal is the key, contingencies that are not time bound.

Comment: In a Science article entitled "The Holy Spirit: The Feminine Aspect Of the Godhead” http://www.pistissophia.org/The_Holy_Spirit/the_holy_spirit.html

Comment: The title asks one question, the body asks a different question. That qualifies as "unclear what you're asking."

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Did Caleb's edit improve the clarity?  I think it's clear but it may be a broad, since the tag says "early church" but the question is "any teachings in Church history"

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It looks like Caleb was returning the question to something more like what the OP originally asked. I've made further edits to bring it, I think, even closer to the OP's original intent. Now that I've looked at the edit train, it's clear that the contradictory title and body were not in the OP's original question, but were the result of edits made by others over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at my article from several years ago [The Motherhood of the Holy Spirit in the 18th century Brudergemeine in Church History](http://zinzendorf.com/pages/index.php?id=holy-spirit-as-mother).

Zinzendorf claimed that there was precedent for this in early Christian theology, especially Ephraim. Trudy Beyark just published a book on the feminine side of God which looks at feminine language in many Christian traditions, including Catholicism.

Comment: Just read your article, thank you for answering my question!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you checked out our [about] page yet? While I appreciate the addition to the conversation here I think you've failed to address the root of this question: are there any early church teachings from this perspective?

Answer (score 5):

The theory of Matriarchal Holy Spirit is a *Gnostic Heresy*. It doesn't have anything to do with the scriptures.

Jesus addresses the Holy Spirit by the masculine gender in the following verses of John 14:26

> But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my
>   name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I
>   have said to you.

And also in John 15

> John 15:26 But when the Comforter is come, whom I will send unto you
>   from the Father, even the Spirit of truth, which proceedeth from the
>   Father, he shall testify of me.

Those who believe in a Matriarchal Holy Spirit are simply alluding to the fact that many in this world tends to understand God by things of the world that are
clearly visible.  They believe that since the human family on earth comprises
of a husband, wife, and son, the family in heaven too should comprise of God the
Father, the Holy Spirit as Mother, and Jesus as the Son.

Also remember the present day proponents of the idea of a Matriarchal Holy Spirit are some of the feminist groups and not any seriously religious groups.

Comment: Perhaps a linguistic expert could shed light here.  The word translated above as "he" is "autos", a Greek neuter noun.  Further any reference to Holy Spirit by Christ would have been rendered from Hebrew, which "Spirit" in Hebrew is a feminine noun.

Comment: Ruwach is the Hebrew word for Spirit (blueletterbible.org)

Comment: A correction, the word translated above as "he" is "ekeinos", a Greek pronoun meaning “he, she, it” not “autos”.

Comment: Identifying that this was taught by the Gnostic's and identified as a heresy is useful, but this answer has really skirted the issue that was actually asked about. A defense of orthodox teaching is **not required or even desirable** on this question, just a run down of what groups have accepted this teaching and their relation to other churches.

Comment: Can you address the comments that Rick made about translation and implied gender?  @Rick Just as likely that Jesus was speaking in Aramaic, wasn't it?   And the Gospel of John was written IIRC in Koine Greek.

Comment: Other than mentioning Gnosticism, this simply doesn't answer the question asked. Instead, it argues against the subject matter of the question.

Comment: This answer seems to assume that all Gnostic teachings are (considered) completely false. They aren't. (Heresies, in general, are not necessarily total negations of the faith, as much as caricature-like simplifications or exaggerations). As far as scripture is concerned, we are born anew, by water and the Spirit; since people are born of their mothers and fathers, and since the Spirit is not the Father (nor the Son), the conclusion follows. The ancient Syriac-speaking Church Fathers (which are neither modern, nor feminist, let alone heretical) used similar imagery when discussing pneumatology.

Comment: Concerning your next-to-last paragraph, see Genesis 1:26-27 and 2:24, then compare it to John 10:30. A patristic approach can be found [here](http://www.marquette.edu/maqom/adameve.html).